# Margin/Padding Left of a Bootstrap Navbar with a hidden title?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap Navbar which has a hidden title in all sizes except XS. Well, in sizes SM, MD, LG there is a space between border-left of the Navbar and my first MenuItem, and I wanna suprime this. Nevertheless, on the right margin do not happen this. This is my code:

```
<nav id="idNavMenu" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">

    {/*<a class="navbar-brand" href="/inicio"><img id="idFotoLogotipo" width="200px" src="./assets/images/cabecera_CE.jpg"/></a>*/}

    <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs-block" href="http://www.upct.es/"><span id="idTextoLogotipo">UPCT</span></a>

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Menú</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
            <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/inicio' index={true} menuItemActive="inicio">Inicio</MenuNavItem>
            <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/nueva_incidencia' menuItemActive="nueva_incidencia">Nueva Incidencia</MenuNavItem>
            <MenuNavItem to='/alumno/mis_incidencias' menuItemActive="mis_incidencias">Mis Incidencias</MenuNavItem>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <MenuNavItem to=''><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span> Salir</MenuNavItem>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

How could I solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Ok. It is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some CSS to remove the `padding-left` on larger screen widths...

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .navbar-ex1-collapse {
        padding-left: 0;
    }
}
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/6uRPnswd7J

Comment: Thank you! Solved.